# Allow user to download a simple text file to client machine without HTML tags in JSP

Tags: jsp, download

In my JSP code (no servlet, just JSP) I would like the user to download a plain text file to their client machine.

There are plenty of examples yes, but all of them seem to produce the same problem.

the problem is once the file is downloaded it always contains the flowing HTML in the file before the text that i am writing to the file

so if i write `this is my text data` to the out stream for download it will look like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<body>
this is my text data
```

how do I stop the HTML tags from getting into the download ?

I am using the implicit response "out" object provided by JSP
I've tried all different ways of setting the response

```
String text = "this is my text data";
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                 "attachment;filename=downloadname.txt");
out.write(text);
```

and again the result will be a file that looks like this in my download folder

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<body>
this is my text data
```

Comment: Post the code of your JSP. But really, JSP is not, at all, the good tool to do that. Use a servlet. You wouldn't hit nails with a screwdriver, would you?

Comment: <%response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTECT-STREAM");

Comment: <%response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTECT-STREAM"); response.setContentType("text/plain"); String disHeader = "Attachment: Filename\"report.txt\""; response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader); String reportText = (String)session.getAttribute("reportDownload"); out.write(reportText);